# Immediate nested DOM declaration in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get a nested DOM element in javascript instead of using jQuery?
Example:

```
$('#id') = document.getElementById('id');
```

I would like to convert this jQuery selector `$('.nav > li')` to javascript. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you are looking for [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Oh, sorry @Georg, took too much time to remember how to make a link with markdown and didn't saw your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You have a really nice function called [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which can select elements with css queries.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.nav > li');
```

If you plan to use it more than once, you can also use a var so it'll feel like using jQuery

```
var _ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)
var menuItems = _('.nav > li');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the answers suggesting `querySelectorAll`, here's how you would achieve that with old school DOM operations.

```
var selected = [];

// get all elements that have the class 'nav' (.nav)
var navs = document.getElementsByClassName('nav');

var i, j, children;

// iterate over each nav and get a list of their direct children (.nav >)
for(i = 0; i < navs.length; i++) {
  children = navs[i].children;

  // iterate over the children and select if the tag is li (.nav > li)
  for(j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
    if(children[j].tagName === 'LI') {
      selected.push(children[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Also serves as a good example of why declarative programming is better suited to this kind of task.